# Import programs in the same folder python

Tags: python, import

I'm importing statsmod.py, which is stored in the same folder as the program I am running. I'm importing it like this:

```
import statsmod
```

When I run the program, however, I get the following:

```
raise TypeError(msg.format(type(x).__name__)) from None
```

Am I not importing it correctly?

Comment: I think you are having conflicts with other libraries that have python calls in the same way

Comment: note: there is [`statistics` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html) in stdlib already.

Comment: `statistics` is a built-in module in python. You might need to rename your module.

Comment: I just changed my module name to "statsmod" and it still gives me the same error.

Comment: Then I suspect the error is in `statsmod.py`. Have you tried running it by itself?

Comment: could you add your code for statsmod?